# JPA Composite PK referenced by FKs in One to Many Relationship

Tags: spring, jpa, foreign-keys, one-to-many, composite-key

I am trying to map the tables below into JPA. The relationships are **one-to-many** between **user_tax and tax** and **user_tax and user**. It has confused me the fact that i have a composite primary key, and i need to map the foreign keys to these 2 keys.

the error message: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: entity.Tax.user_tax in entity.UserTax.taxs`

```
             tax           user_tax         user
           --------        --------        ------
         PK|t_id  |--------| t_id |PK-FK  |u_name|
           |t_name|   PK-FK| u_id |-------|u_id  | PK
           |      |        | name |       |      |
```

Here is my Entities:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "user")
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    public class User implements Serializable {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
         private Long id;

       @Column(name="u_name")
         private String uname;

          getters + setters
        }
```

---

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "tax")
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    public class Tax implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
          private Long id;

        @Column(name = "t_name")
          private String tname;
```

---

```
   @Embeddable
    public class UserTaxId implements Serializable {

      @Column(name="u_id")
        private Long uId;

        @Column(name="t_id")
        private Long tId;
```

---

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "user_tax")
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    public class UserTax implements Serializable {

      @EmbeddedId
        private UserTaxId userTaxId;

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user_tax")
        private List<User> users;

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user_tax")
        private List<Tax> taxs;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Your 1:n mappings are backwards (i.e. a `UserTax` can have only a single `User` and a single `Tax`) and you are using a derived identity. Try mapping `UserTax` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_tax")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class UserTax implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserTaxId userTaxId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("uId") // maps uId attribute of embedded id
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("tId") // maps tId attribute of embedded id
    private Tax tax;

    ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I will post here what worked for me after 3 days of research.

Brian Vosburgh correctly posted the UserTax class:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "user_tax")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class UserTax implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserTaxId userTaxId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("uId") // maps uId attribute of embedded id
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("tId") // maps tId attribute of embedded id
    private Tax tax;

    ...
}
```

However, i was getting error meassages and my code wasn't compiling. Then i also had to edit the User and Tax classes:

```
 @Entity
     @Table(name = "user")
     @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
        public class User implements Serializable {

           @Id
           @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
             private Long id;

           @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "tid",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
        )
        private List<UserTax> tax = new ArrayList<>();

           @Column(name="u_name")
             private String uname;

              getters + setters
            }

    @Entity
     @Table(name = "tax")
     @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
        public class Tax implements Serializable {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
              private Long id;

           @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "uid",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
        )
        private List<UserTax> taxs = new ArrayList<>();

            @Column(name = "t_name")
              private String tname;

    setters+getters

    }
```

Here is the link where i found the solution to my problem: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/